# How to change the file name of automated chrome download option via python selinium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to save the file into a specific name by changing the default name

which is popping up by the python selenium download button click

I tried the below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.prompt_for_download":True,
         "download.default_directory":
                    r"C:\Music\\",#IMPORTANT - ENDING SLASH V IMPORTANT
         "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r".\bot_automation\drivers\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)


driver.get('https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-the-right-mobile-devices')
gotit = driver.find_element(By.ID,'accept-cookie-notification')
gotit.click()
downloadcsv = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.icon-csv')
downloadcsv.click()



#the below codes are not working need to replace that 
file_window=driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
file_window.clear()
file_window.send_keys("Hii text")
#till this and aslo need to send enter to save the file too

time.sleep(5)
# driver.close()  # closes currently active window
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

then the below popup is opening need to change the file name and save it

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Selenium to Handle Windows based Dialogs, selenium can only interact with Browser, you can add a Sikuli Script as part of Your execution to handle this file rename and saving
IF you don't want to change the name and just save it without handling the save as dialog , you can do so using below code

```
chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver"

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = Options()

# this is the preference we're passing
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

If you do want to change the name and then save the file , Add a Sikuli script
Read more in Below link
https://sikulix.github.io/docs/scripts/python/